# Como fazer um viewpager igual do google play?

Tags: android, viewpager

Caros,

Alguém sabe como faço um layout como do google play? 
Quando a Tablayout é selecionada, o viewpager muda a view inteira, não somente a parte de baixo (ou de cima)

Preciso fazer a mudança desta forma. 
Consigo fazer muito parecido mas não está igual.

Tenho que mudar a viewpage de cima, com novas imagens dependendo da tablayout clickada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta seu código amigo, senão a gente não consegue ter ideia da forma que você está fazendo!

Answer (score 1):

Isso, ao que me parece, é um viewpager que contém um conjunto de imageviews, assim como uma galeria de fotos. O viewpager, obviamente, pega somente metade da tela (o viewpager age como se fosse uma div do html).
Então, a estrutura ficaria + ou - assim:

```
 ---activity|---layoutDeCima----viewpager----imageviews
            |---layoutDeBaixo----tabs com 2 fragmentos dentro---cardviews
```

No onClick das tabs, mata o viewpager do layoutDeCima e cria um novo.

Sinto muito não colar código aqui.É porque é praticamente um projeto inteiro.
Para fazer essas tabs de modo mais fácil, recomendo essa biblioteca:
[SmartTab](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)
Para os indicadores brancos, recomendo essa: [CircleIndicator](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator)

Comment: ja estava tentando fazer desta forma.

Mas não consigo "matar" a viewpager, e recria-la novamente.


Ja tentei diversos métodos mas não funciona. Apenas aparece o dados do primeiro Adapter que é setado.

Estou setando 2 adapter, um para cada selected da Tab

Comment: Você criou um fragment para cada tab ou pôs tudo na MainActivity?
Tente criar um fragment para cada tab. Controle cada fragment separadamente...cada um na sua classe.

Comment: Ta sendo feito assim.

O problema é a viewpager, que esta na activity. Só carrega uma vez, depois quando tento por outro adapter, ele ja não surte efeito. Adiciona mais não muda.

Comment: usou o adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Comment: Sim. 
To achando que essa viewpeger precisa ficar no fragment. Ficaria muito estranho

Comment: É comum o uso de viewpager em fragmentos na minha opinião. Pelo menos não vejo como usar ele nesse caso a não ser em um fragmento.